# Binding multiple elements to multiple tables using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am back again with another basic Angular question. Well, I was easily able to read from database and display data on view using ASP.Net MVC and AngularJS. The below example is a very simple one:

View:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
        <td>{{p.pName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Angular Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Home/GetProducts')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.products = result;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

MVC Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetProducts()
    {
        var db = new testDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from pObj in db.Products
                          select new
                          {
                              pId = pObj.Id,
                              pName = pObj.nme,
                              pDesc = pObj.descr,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
    }
```

**My Question is:**
I want to add another element in my view, let's say a select tab. And I want to bind that element to users table where I can list all users.

Can you please help me on this, I am very confused on how to do this.

I tried to do the following with no luck:

```
<select ng-model="getUsers">
  <option ng-options="x in users">{{x.ufName + " " + x.ulName}}</option>
</select>
```

//////

```
$scope.getUsers = function () {
    $http.post('/Home/GetUsers')
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.users= result;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

////

```
public JsonResult GetUsers()
    {
        var db = new testDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          select new
                          {
                              uId = userObj.Id,
                              ufName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              ulName = userObj.usrLastName,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
    }
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice
The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard **then** method instead.

Comment: I did not understand. Would you please give me an example?

Comment: $scope.getUsers = function () {
    $http.post('/Home/GetUsers')
        .then(
function (result) {
            $scope.users= result;
        },
function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

Comment: Ok, where is the part that calls the getUsers function in the view? This is what confuses me

Comment: If you are calling the users one time, I would put the call on the controller, just like you did on getProducts, without the $scope.getUsers wrapping.

Comment: Ok, but how? Sorry I am new to this. How I would write the $http.get in this case?

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ng-options on the select, and not the options.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

[resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

EDIT to clear what I said on the comment.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Home/GetProducts').then(
        function (result) {
            // success
            $scope.products = result;
        },
        function (data) {
            // fail
            console.log(data);
        }
    );

    $http.get('/Home/GetUserss').then(
        function (result) {
            // success
            $scope.users = result;
        },
        function (data) {
            // fail
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
 });
```

Comment: I would be very much appreciate it if you give me an example. I tried this with no luck

Comment: The idea is, if you look at my Angular controller, the code that get the MVC controller is inside a function.

Comment: @AhmedAlsahli follow the resource link for more examples.

Comment: It doesn't help. In the examples, the binding done to an array which is a very easy to do. What I need is binding to database tables which means I need to use ajax (get) in my angularjs controller